# Revoking AIK Key

Tags: cryptography, attacks, key-management, tpm, remote-attestation

How can I prevent attacks via compromised Attestation Identity Key (AIK) keys, such as having an attacker forging the cryptographic signature of an AIK key on [TPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module)?

Answer (score 1):

AIKs are signed by Certificate Authorities (CA) and like any certificate, they can be revoked in the same way.

Checking for revocation status is mandated by the [TCG specification](https://www.trustedcomputinggroup.org/files/resource_files/51D1302B-1A4B-B294-D05515C7DEF98202/TPM_Keys_for_Platform_Identity_v1_0_r3_Final.pdf). See page 43.